# jQtouch.. nothing is getting displayed on the screen

Tags: android, jquery, android-webview, jqtouch

I'm very new to jQtouch. I'm following [this](http://ofps.oreilly.com/titles/9781449383268/chapAnimation.html#addingJqtToTheParty) tutorial. But because of this updated version of jQtouch I'm not being able to follow it exactly. I'm using eclipse to develop an app on android. Now, this is the code I'm trying to run

```
    <html>
    <head>
        <!--<style type="text/css" media="screen">@import "themes/css/jqtouch.css";</style>
        <link type="text/css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" href="themes/css/jqtouch.css" />
        <script src="src/lib/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="src/jqtouch.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>-->


        <style type="text/css" media="screen">@import "themes/css/jqtouch.css";</style>
        <script src="src/lib/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="src/jqtouch.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
        <script src="extensions/jqt.floaty.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>



        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            var jQT = new $.jQTouch({
            icon: 'jqtouch.png',
            statusBar: 'black-translucent',
            preloadImages: []
        });
        <title>Kilo</title>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id="home">
    <div class="toolbar">
        <h1>Kilo</h1>
    </div>
    <ul class="edgetoedge">
        <li class="arrow"><a href="#dates">Dates</a></li>
        <li class="arrow"><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Now, I'm getting no error in eclipse. The activity is working fine. But due to some unknown reason I'm getting an empty page. Also being new to jQtouch I can switch to anything else like jquery framework directly if I can have problems with jQtouch in complex tasks.
Thanks. :)

Comment: perhaps you have javascript error, preventing the page from loading
Where's the script tag closer? That's the problem

Comment: Hey thanks for pointing out that silly mistake. But it now shows that $.jQTouch isn't a defined constructor.

Comment: Check to see are the script files loaded indeed

Comment: Yes.. they are getting loaded. I checked it in chrome on my laptop. They're getting loaded though it still shows the same error that function $.jQTouch isn't defined.

Answer (score 0):

You are not closeing the script tag

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    var jQT = $.jQTouch({
        icon: 'jqtouch.png',
        statusBar: 'black-translucent',
        preloadImages: []
    });
</script><!-- Close it -->
```

**UPDATE**

Get rid of the `new` .
Follow the example you're making up stuff of your own.

If you insist on using constructor that is the proper way:

```
var jQT = new jQTouch({

   option: value

});
```

Comment: Please try both approaches but carefully check every detail and if it fails again let me know